# Gracenote: how to work with the third party (such as Amazon.com) music catalogues?

Tags: gracenote

Why do I get only the `appletrackid` datasource?

```
config.setProperty("content.link.preferredSource","Amazon");
searchByText (GNSearchResultReady resultReady, GNConfig config, String artist, String albumTitle, String trackTitle)

All time I get only `DATASOURCE="appletrackid"
```

Is it possible to search in the third party music catalogues by mood ? How to do it?

How to get the list of the all supported "content.link.preferredSource" music catalogues ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your client ID will be 'entitled' for certain third party ('external') IDs.

If you omit the preferred source, you should get *all* of the IDs you are entitled for in your results. (Note that the external IDs can appear at the album and track level.)

If you aren't entitled for an external ID that you need, you'd need to contact Gracenote to see about changing your client entitlements.